# Why can't texify work after a failed texify without manually deleting auxiliary files?

Tags: winedt, miktex2.9, texify

I am working with WinEdt 10.3 with Miktex 2.9. My problem is that after a failed texify, I have to mannually delete the auxiliary files generated from the failed texify to make it work, otherwise even if I have corrected the mistakes in the tex file, texify still refuses to compile properly. I wonder why this is happening, and how I can avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It can happen after a faulty compilation that the auxiliary files are so broken that one has to remove them. But if it happens regularly it often indicates that a compilation has been stopped in the wrong way. Don't kill it by clicking on the x in a window to close it, type x on your keyboard and hit enter instead.

Comment: It worked! Thanks to Ulrike Fischer!